# node-webkit: unexpected "undefined is not a function" on String.prototype.includes()

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, node-webkit

`node-webkit` is erroring out on ln 208 in the screenshot below. Strangely, if I run the exact same code in my Chrome browser using a JavaScript Debug configuration in WebStorm, everything works fine. I've read about `.includes()` being introduced as part of ES6 but even with `.has()` and `.contains()` alternatives, the same "undefined is not a function" js error is thrown.

[image]

Comment: You should just install the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill). Apparently, node-webkit is not (yet) a (complete) ES6 environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no idea why it doesn't work but I ended up just replacing the statement with a jQuery utility function like so:

```
if (!$.inArray(dw,dws)) {}
```

This works fine in node-webkit and Chrome.